# Does the input have to be inside the form in order for the autocomplete to work?

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, html-input

I have an `<input>` that gets generated from the javascript. It has `id`, `name` and `autocomplete="on"` but the browser does not remember the previous input.

It is not in a form, gets generated/destroyed dynamically.

Any way to make autocomplete work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the input have to be inside the form in order for the
>   autocomplete to work

`input` element need not be inside the `form`.

Since it's the browser feature, make sure that the `name` and `type` attributes must be generic say for `email`, the name must be `email` for `input` which should be used by most of the sites.

You can check the snippet with email. You will get your most used email addresses.

```html
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" />
```

Same with dynamically created `input` elements.

```js
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<input type='email' name='email' autocomplete'on'>";
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: That works, but what if the input is added through javascript?

Comment: I checked it worked the same with elements created dynamically by `JS`. Check the new snippet.

Comment: hmm, maybe `email` is a common name that has been populated by the browser on other forms.

Comment: Yes. That's right. We must use the common names to make good use of this autofill feature